# Composing two functions to get a function that returns HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

This is probably a very naive question about [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless):

Suppose I have functions `A => M[B]` and `B => M[C]`. How can I compose them to get a new function `A => M[B::C::HNil]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do this generically you can use Scalaz's `Arrow`:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def andThenButKeep[Arr[_, _]: Arrow, A, B, C](
  f: Arr[A, B],
  g: Arr[B, C]
): Arr[A, (B, C)] = f >>> (Category[Arr].id &&& g)
```

Or if you want an `HList` instead of a tuple:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import shapeless._, shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._

def andThenButKeep[Arr[_, _], A, B, C](
  f: Arr[A, B],
  g: Arr[B, C]
)(implicit Arr: Arrow[Arr]): Arr[A, B :: C :: HNil] =
  f >>> (Arr.id &&& g) >>> Arr.arr((_: (B, C)).productElements)
```

Now you'd wrap your functions in a Kleisli arrow:

```
type OptionFunc[A, B] = Kleisli[Option, A, B]

val f: OptionFunc[Int, String] = Kleisli(i => Some("a" * i))
val g: OptionFunc[String, Int] = Kleisli(s => Some(s.length))

val c = andThenButKeep(f, g)
```

And then:

```
scala> println(c.run(10))
Some(aaaaaaaaaa :: 10 :: HNil)
```

You could make this a little less fussy about type inference (but also less generic) by restricting the arrow to a Kleisli arrow over your `M`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define that `M[_]` is some form of a `Monad` so you can `flatMap` it, I chose to use the `scalaz` `Monad`:

```
  import scalaz._, Scalaz._
  import shapeless._
  def compose[M[_] : Monad, A, B, C](f: A => M[B], g: B => M[C]): A => M[B :: C :: HNil] = {
    a => f(a).flatMap(b => g(b).map(c => b :: c :: HNil))
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, `scalaz` is Ok.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
for {
  b <- f(a)
  c <- g(b)
} yield b :: c :: HNil
```

which of course expands to

```
f(a) flatMap { b =>
  g(b) map { c => b :: c :: HNil }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to do it point-free but thank you for the answer anyway.